# Java: How to calculate time complexity of a program?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following program. In a case where it has multiple functions, do I combine the time complexity of each or just take the highest order time complexity out of all of them?

I believe the `find()` has a time complexity of n and `isCompound` has a time complexity of n has well. Is that correct?

Thank you and will be sure to vote up and accept answer.

```
private static String[] find(String[] array) {
    Set<String> words = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
    Set<String> otherWords = new HashSet<>(words);
    for (Iterator<String> i = words.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String next = i.next();
        otherWords.remove(next);
        if (isCompound(next, otherWords)) {
            i.remove();
        } else {
            otherWords.add(next);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isCompound(String string, Set<String> otherWords) {
    if (otherWords.contains(string)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (String word : otherWords) {
        if (string.startsWith(word)) {
            return isCompound(string.replaceAll("^" + word, ""), otherWords);
        }
        if (string.endsWith(word)) {
            return isCompound(string.replaceAll(word + "$", ""), otherWords);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how the functions interact.

Comment: Loops as in `for loops` in your program would have a `linear time complexity` i.e. `O(n)` and if sequence would be `O(1)`

Comment: Please note that you've got two variables here: the number of words and the length of each word. Think about what happens for example if your arrays contain only a single word that consists of a billion characters. Your limiting factor will definitely not be the number of words in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like time complexity of a program. We calculate time complexity for algorithms or, in the context of programming, for individual (atomic) functions.

We benchmark programs (which may consist of multiple functions) by measuring their running time in tools like profilers. **Imagine if a program contains hundreds of source files, how can you expect to calculate its time complexity?**

To analyze the complexities for `find` and `isCompound`, we certainly need to know the complexities for the functions called inside them, like `otherWords.remove(next)`, `otherWords.add(next)`, `string.replaceAll("^" + word, "")` or `otherWords.contains(string)`.

If you know for certain what their complexities are, then we can compute the complexities for your functions. And even if you calculate all the complexities, that too would be an approximation made for very large inputs. So, you decide what you really wish to calculate.

EDIT: To calculate the complexities for your program, I suggest you break down each of the library function you called and try to analyze them. For instance, since `otherWords` is a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), we can infer that `otherWords.contains(string)` (lookup operation in a hash table) might take `O(1)` (big-O) time.

Comment: So there is no such thing as program time complexity? And time complexity is only based on functions? Sorry but how would I calculate time complexities for those libraries?

Comment: You can indeed compute a program's time complexity, but, either you need to know the time complexity of every called library function, or you must implement all those called functions by writing algorithms yourself.