# How to calculate the time complexity when you use an API method?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am learning how to calculate the time and space complexity recently. I know how to calculate the basic one. However, when it involves some pre-built method, I got confused. For example, the code below uses the indexOf() method in the String class, how do I calculate? Thanks!

```
class Solution {
    public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
        String prefix = strs[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < strs.length; i ++){
            while(strs[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0){
                prefix = prefix.substring(0,prefix.length()-1);
            }
        }return prefix;
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40642392/1531124 : "There is nothing like time complexity of a program. We calculate time complexity for algorithms or, in the context of programming, for individual (atomic) functions."

Comment: Alternatively: it is always a good exercise to turn to the **source code** of that library call. And then you can try to analyse that yourself, to get an idea what is going on. Plenty of such key library calls even state their Big-O characteristics somewhere in the corresponding javadoc.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean calculating the the complexity of this kind of algorithm is not a must especially in an interview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in comments, this existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40642392/1531124) suggests:

> There is nothing like time complexity of a program. We calculate time complexity for algorithms or, in the context of programming, for individual (atomic) functions.

But to answer the implicit "how to go about this in an interview?":

- In the above example, understand that there are the explicit loops. If you focus on that, you can estimate how many times the inner loop body gets executed
- From there, you could "mentally" inline that library call
- Leading to: you would suggest to inspect the source code of the library methods to understand *its* runtime cost

Comment: @CollinD My bad, you are absolutely correct. Fixed it!